# href no muestra "#" en mi aplicación con React y Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, reactjs, inertia.js

Hola soy nuevo en Laravel, Inertia y React y tengo un problema al querer colocar una almohadilla "#" en el href de la etiqueta  para que no me genere una petición.

```
<Link key={subItem.name} href={subItem?.href || "#"} className="-m-3 flex items-start rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-50">
      <subItem.icon className={`flex-shrink-0 ${menuIconDimensions} text-indigo-600`} aria-hidden="true" />
      <div className="ml-4">
           <p className="text-base font-14 text-gray-900" data-cy={`menu-${t(subItem?.name || "")}`}>{t(subItem?.name || "")}</p>
           <p className="mt-1 font-12 text-gray-500">{t(subItem?.description || "")}</p>
      </div>
</Link>
```

Pongo otra letra o simbolo y sí aparece menos el "#" alguna idea?

Comment: estas usando next?

Comment: Estoy usando Inertia

Comment: intenta agregarla entre parensetesis? `{(subItem?.href || "#")}`

Answer (score 0):

Si agregar el símbolo `#` no te funciona puedes también probar a utilizar `href="javascript:void(0)"` en tus etiquetas `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

Usa `"#x"` (`"#"` seguido por cualquier otra cadena) en lugar de solo `"#"`.

#### ¿Por qué?

Revisando el código fuente del componente `Link` de Inertia React se puede observar por qué al poner `"#"`, el atributo `href` desaparece. Según el archivo [packages/inertia-react/src/Link.js](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia/blob/master/packages/inertia-react/src/Link.js), la propiedad `href` enviada al componente es transformada por una función llamada `mergeDataIntoQueryString` que recibe varios argumentos. La función se define en [packages/inertia/src/url.ts](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia/blob/master/packages/inertia/src/url.ts), y actualmente está definida así:

```ts
export function mergeDataIntoQueryString(
  method: Method,
  href: URL|string,
  data: Record<string, FormDataConvertible>,
  qsArrayFormat: 'indices'|'brackets' = 'brackets',
): [string, Record<string, FormDataConvertible>] {
  const hasHost = /^https?:\/\//.test(href.toString())
  const hasAbsolutePath = hasHost || href.toString().startsWith('/')
  const hasRelativePath = !hasAbsolutePath && !href.toString().startsWith('#') && !href.toString().startsWith('?')
  const hasSearch = href.toString().includes('?') || (method === Method.GET && Object.keys(data).length)
  const hasHash = href.toString().includes('#')

  const url = new URL(href.toString(), 'http://localhost')

  if (method === Method.GET && Object.keys(data).length) {
    url.search = qs.stringify(deepmerge(qs.parse(url.search, { ignoreQueryPrefix: true }), data), {
      encodeValuesOnly: true,
      arrayFormat: qsArrayFormat,
    })
    data = {}
  }

  return [
    [
      hasHost ? `${url.protocol}//${url.host}` : '',
      hasAbsolutePath ? url.pathname : '',
      hasRelativePath ? url.pathname.substring(1) : '',
      hasSearch ? url.search : '',
      hasHash ? url.hash : '',
    ].join(''),
    data,
  ]
}
```

Para el caso, si la propiedad `href` fuera `"#"` podemos seguir el flujo de la función, o mejor aun usar un depurador, para ver qué sucede con la propiedad. En este caso el argumento `method` es `'get'`, ya que no se está incluyendo en el elemento JSX y se usa el valor default definido para el componente, el valor de data es `{}` y el de qsArrayFormat es `'brackets'`, ambos por la misma razón. Podemos omitir las primeras líneas y ver directamente el valor de retorno, que es un arreglo de dos valores: la URL transformada y los datos si es que se quiere hacer una petición `POST`, etc. Observemos el primer elemento:

```ts
[
  hasHost ? `${url.protocol}//${url.host}` : '',
  hasAbsolutePath ? url.pathname : '',
  hasRelativePath ? url.pathname.substring(1) : '',
  hasSearch ? url.search : '',
  hasHash ? url.hash : '',
].join('')
```

El valor de `"#"` para `href` no incluye un protocolo (como `http:` o `https:`), ni un host (como en `http://localhost:8000`), ni una ruta (como `/index.html`), ni un query (como en `/search?q=time`); por lo anterior los cuatro primeros valores son cadenas vacías:

```ts
[
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  hasHash ? url.hash : '',
].join('')
```

Queda revisar el valor de `url.hash`, donde `url` se define como `url = new URL("#", 'http://localhost')`. Si se evalúa esta expresión en la consola de JavaScript o de Node.js se genera un objeto `URL` así:

```
URL {
  href: 'http://localhost/#',
  origin: 'http://localhost',
  protocol: 'http:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: 'localhost',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: '',
  pathname: '/',
  search: '',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
  hash: ''
}
```

Se observa que la propiedad `hash` es una cadena vacía, lo que no ocurre si se usa, por ejemplo `"#x"`:

```
URL {
  href: 'http://localhost/#x',
  origin: 'http://localhost',
  protocol: 'http:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: 'localhost',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: '',
  pathname: '/',
  search: '',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
  hash: '#x'
}
```

Finalmente, como `url.hash` es una cadena vacía la URL transformada queda así:

```ts
[
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
].join('')
```

Es decir, al transformarse con `mergeDataIntoQueryString`, `href` queda convertido en una cadena vacía, que puesto en un elemento HTML `a` equivale a un enlace a la URL actual.